# What is the background needed for Von Neumann Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, von-neumann-algebras

I've found a book on Von Neumann algebras and I thought it could be interesting, but I have no idea on what is needed for studying it and the book also doesn't mention it.

Comment: It depends on the book - which one do you have?  At the very minimum you will need a serious course on functional analysis under your belt.

Comment: @PaulSiegel [V.S. Sunder - An Invitation to von Neumann Algebras (Universitext)](http://www.amazon.com/Invitation-von-Neumann-Algebras-Universitext/dp/0387963561).

Comment: @GustavoBandeira so you think you answered your question? In this case you can share your ideas by posting an answer

Comment: @Norbert I didn't answer my question.

Comment: I would say functional analysis and linear algebra.  But also, the subject is rather complicated, so if you read the book and only understand part of it, you are doing very well.  I have speed read a few books on von Neumann algebras, so I have a bit of the sense of the big picture.

Comment: You can pick up what you need as long as you read the book. Generally speaking, basic functional analysis, group theory, measure theory is enough unless you plan to read advanced topics on II$_1$ factors theory, where ergodic theory is indispensable.